# How do I install package from amazon-linux-extras using Puppet?

Tags: puppet, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to set up a Puppet module to install PHP 7.3 on Amazon Linux 2. It is available as a amazon-linux-extras package.

I could simply install it using CLI:

```
amazon-linux-extras install php7.3
```

But I would like to define it as a package and ensure it is installed, like this:

```
package { "php7.3":
  ensure => installed,
  provider => 'amazon-linux-extras'
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot set package `provider` to `amazon-linux-extras` as such provider doesn't exist.

What would be the correct way to install this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, it appears that Puppet does not support the amazon-linux-extras utility.

Arguably, a new type/provider should be created to support amazon-linux-extras. It could live in Puppet Core, if you raised a feature request that is accepted. Or, you could write your own and release it as a module on the Puppet Forge, if you know how write custom types and providers.

In the mean time, it is easy to write a defined type to solve this problem using exec.

```puppet
define al::amazon_linux_extras(
  Enum['present'] $ensure = present,
  ) {
  $pkg = $name
  exec { "amazon-linux-extras install -y $pkg":                                                                                                                        
    unless => "amazon-linux-extras list | grep -q '${pkg}=.*enabled'",                                                                                                 
    path   => '/usr/bin',                                                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Usage:

```
al::amazon_linux_extras { 'php7.3':
  ensure => present,
}
```

Further explanation:

- I assumed you would place your defined type in a module `al`. But it could be a profile etc. E.g. `profile::amazon_linux_extras` is another possibility.
- I implemented `ensure => present` for readability only, i.e. it doesn't actually do anything, and also in case you decide to later implement `ensure => absent` or `ensure => latest` etc.